# Flutter firebase trigger email implementation

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-extensions

I've been trying to create a contact form for my flutter project. The contact form is composed of two steps. First, the user provides their email and then describes their issue. Once the user presses submit, I want to receive an email on my end. I've look at several packages like [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) and [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender). However, they don't seem to offer good solutions; mailer requires that I provide the password to my email address in my code (opening up the possibility for vulnerabilities). Flutter_email_sender simply opens up an email app on the phone.

Recently I've come across the perfect solution, Firebase's new extension [Trigger Email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email). Although the extension seems promising, I can't find any resources outlining proper implementation of Trigger Email in Flutter.

Can you please provide an example of how Trigger Email can be implemented in Flutter project?

Comment: "Use this extension to render and send emails that contain the information from documents added to a specified Cloud Firestore collection." So to send an email you write a document to Cloud Firestore. For examples of writing to Cloud Firestore from Flutter, see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Comment: Oh.. this is much simpler than I thought, thank you!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it also possible to attach files (e.g. from Firebase Storage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) of the extension:

> Use this extension to render and send emails that contain the information from documents added to a specified Cloud Firestore collection.

So to send an email you write a document to Cloud Firestore. For examples of writing to Cloud Firestore from Flutter, see the FlutterFire documentation for [examples of this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage).

Comment: Thank you for your help!